# Uploading image to firebase using expo react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am working on an app and I am using expo, I want to make sure each user can upload an image to firebase, and later publish this image on the profile page.

Using expo this is how I upload images:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(pickerResult);
    handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
  };
```

the result in the console is:

```
Object {
  "cancelled": false,
  "height": 312,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fallergyn-app-77bfd368-65fd-43f9-8c34-9c35cef42c25/ImagePicker/daaa229c-c352-4994-ae18-ca2dbb3534ce.jpg",
  "width": 416,
}
```

and this is how I upload to the firebase:

```
const handleImagePicked = async (pickerResult) => {
    try {
      if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
        setImage(pickerResult.uri);
        await uploadImageAsync(pickerResult.uri);
        console.log("done");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert("Upload failed, sorry :(");
    } finally {
    }
  };

  async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    });

    const ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child("images" + Math.random());

    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

    // We're done with the blob, close and release it
    blob.close();
    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

this code works it saves the path of the image this: `"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fallergyn-app-77bfd368-65fd-43f9-8c34-9c35cef42c25/ImagePicker/daaa229c-c352-4994-ae18-ca2dbb3534ce.jpg"` in the firebase under user collection using the uid of the user.

I am not sure if this is good, because I want to make sure the image itself is uploaded to firebase, I saw some threads in StackOverflow regarding this issue either too old or no answers, so I am hoping to get some sort of solution to what I need to do.

if I use

```
const ref = firebase
  .storage()
  .ref()
  .child("images" + Math.random());
  .putFile(uri);
```

this tells me that `putFile is not a function.` the same with `put(uri)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This function returns the path of the saved image from firebase which you will store in the user's document instead.

```
const handleImagePicked = async (pickerResult) => {
      if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
        setImage(pickerResult.uri);
        const result = await uploadImageAsync(pickerResult.uri);
        if(result) {
           console.log('success');
           //save the result path to firestore user document
           return;
        }
        alert("Upload failed, sorry :(");
      }
  };
```

```
export const uploadImageAsync = async (uri: string) => {
  let filename = uri;
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    filename = uri.replace('file:', '');
  }

  const ext = filename.split('.').pop();
  const path = `images/${id}.${ext}`;
  const ref = firebase.storage().ref(path);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(filename);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    await ref.put(blob);
    return path;
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me , using rn-fetch-blob

```
import launchImageLibrary from 'react-native-image-picker'; 
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';


const pickImage = () => {

    let options = {
        mediaType: 'photo',
        quality: 0.5,
    };

    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
 
        console.log('Response = ', response);
        uploadImagePicked(response);

    });

};


const uploadImagePicked = (response) => {

    if (response.fileName) {

        const fileName = response.fileName;
        var storageRef = storage().ref(`receiptImages/${fileName}`);

        RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(response.uri , 'base64')
        .then(data => {
            storageRef.putString(data, 'base64', {contentType:"image/jpg"})
            .on(
                storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
                snapshot => {
                    console.log("snapshot: " + snapshot.state);
                    console.log("progress: " + (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);

                    if (snapshot.state === storage.TaskState.SUCCESS) {
                        console.log("Success");
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("image upload error: " + error.toString());
                },
                () => {
                    storageRef.getDownloadURL()
                    .then((downloadUrl) => {
                        console.log("File available at: " + downloadUrl);
                
                    })
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log("Skipping image upload");  
    }

}
```